# Show items in Categories Scaffold

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, migration, ruby-on-rails-4

**What i have:** `Listings` that when created, can be assigned to a `Category`

I added a `Categories Scaffold`. I added the associations to my Models and i Migrated a `CategoryIdToListings`.

Although Selecting a Category when creating a Listing works, i do not quite understand how i can make *those listings appear under the Category*.

Under

```
localhost:3000/categories/newtron
```

There should be the Listings that have this Category set to.

To render my Listings i use

```
<div id="listings">
  <%= render @listings %>
</div>
```

I know that i have to set on my Categories controller something to my show action

```
def show
end
```

but don't know what exactly.

Can anyone enlighten me on this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `@listings` instance variable in your controller to have actual listings.
This should be enough:

```
def show
  @listings = @category.listings
end
```

Comment: Well it seems that you are my Hero Today :) Thank you !

Comment: `<%= @listing.category.name %>` will be ok. Provided, of course, you're sure that `@listing` has its category.

Comment: yeah just found it :)